# After migrating my application from .Net Core 3.1 to .Net 6.0, the existing linq methods to fetch data from a dbcontext is getting null value

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, .net-3.0

I have migrated my tool from .Net core version 3.1 to 6 and upgrade all the nuget packages accordingly also after migrating I cleaned the solution and build it again. After all these the linq methods (eg. FirstorDefault, SingleorDefault etc) are getting null value from the dbcontext although all were working fine previously. I have checked if dbcontext is getting data or not and it is getting data properly but after querying into it I can not get any data although desired data is present in the datalist.

[this is the query which is filtering object from dbset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Zbb.png).

[Object with highlighted Guid is present in the datalist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRzZM.png).

```cs
EnvironmentConfigDataLib.Entities.Environments app = _dbContext.Environments
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnvironmentId == item.SourceEnvironmentId); //--> this line is getting null although passing guid is present in the DBSet.
```

The same code is working in .Net Core 3.1 version tool.
Does anyone have any idea why this issue is coming?[Packages installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJoZH.png)

I tried to fetch data from DbSet using Linq and it was coming properly for 3.1 version but for 6.0 version same code is getting null value.

Comment: Not an answer, but 1. Do not post code as images 2. do not hit database inside a cycle, especially querying the same info (like `dbContext.Environments.ToList()`).

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks for the tips will keep these on mind. dbContext.Environments.ToList() I have written to see list so that I can check if value is present or not.

Comment: Yes, I understand that (I have noticed that results are not used), still the second point applies, you can get all items by ids using one roundtrip to the database.